# Energy generation via seismic activity

Tags: science-based, engineering, energy, earthquake

In my world, there are small, micro earthquakes that move through the landscape - the kind of thing that you can feel rumbling beneath your feet, but not much more severe - usually. In areas near tectonic boundaries, or like mountain ranges, the earthquakes are more strong.

These microquakes usually are followed by brief little aftershocks - think of it as a ship making a breaking wave, with some disturbances following afterward.

Anyway, my question is, with early industrial technology (let's go with 1840s for simplicity) would it be possible to harness this phenomenon for energy?

I think that it might be difficult at the current time period, as it might require more sensitive equipment, especially for determining the most optimal locations for power generation. Even in its most evolved form, I'd imagine it would be like wind, with intermittent generation, but with periods of frequent seismic activity.

I imagine at this time period it would be like how wind power was utilized at that time too - obviously not for electricity production yet, but there are some small scale uses, like in powering pumps. Maybe it could be even used for factories in the right place.

At this point though I'm kind of lost when it comes to considering what kind of mechanism could capture the energy though. Some kind of thing that transfered the movement of the ground to the rest of the generator, on some kind of isolated system from the ground.

Comment: no its not possible but you can harness the underlying source, geothermal is fairly easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is mechanically possible to do so, but the efficiency for an 1840s tech level would be comically low.

The mechanism is just a tidal harness at the microscale, with a one-way rotor. You'd need millions of them to make any appreciable electrical power from it.  Tidal power works because the oscillation its working with has extreme amplitude and low frequency. The technique still works at low amp, high freq - but the source of power is the distance between the peak and the valley. The smaller that gets, the less work the natural environment is doing to your generator, and subsequently the less energy that generator is producing.

So someone has probably demonstrated that it works as a novel application of physics, but it's laughably impractical.

Comment: Would tidal power (that is, from oceans) be feasible in this time period, like for running a factory?

Comment: @WasatchWind Why not ask a separate question on that as it's a whole different area of technology.

Comment: The short answer is: if you have tides, (and/or significant waves) you've got feasible tidal power near the coasts.

Comment: i'd compare it more to wave power than tidal.

Comment: Cornelis Drebbel built clocks powered by barometric pressure changes in the 17th century. He might have been able to work something out with frequent-enough earthquakes. I seriously doubt he'd have tried to power anything more than a clock, though.

Comment: the problem is earthquakes are rare one off events, you would need to build a new generator fir each impulse. this is not tidal power it is closer to tsunami power, but even harder because it is not transporting something that flows.

Comment: @John In another question, the hypothetical world experiences them with far greater frequency than does Earth.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII they still won't be that frequent, nor predictable, and you still have the concentration problem, you can concentrate water because it flows, rock is a one off widespread movement, the energy is too dispersed to be useful and there is no good way ot concentrate it.

Comment: I believe that's more or less what I said?

Answer (score 2):

## Pressure

Even micro shocks have tremendous energy. How big would you need something to be to slap the ground and get a similar reaction? It's just incredibly powerful.

Vibrations and even the slightest movement can then potentially be harnessed. Place a big flexible container of liquid or air in the ground. Depending on where and how you place it, the container can be compressed or expanded. If this happens there will be pressures or vacuums of extreme powers. If you allow the contents to move in a direction, you already have mechanical movement. Mechanical movement also means heat, as well as the possibility to harness electricity. From heat or electricity you can make light as well.

With big enough containers even the smallest movement can mean huge energies. No sensitive equipment required.

That all being said, I'm not sure if you can make multiple use energy harness systems like this. Possibly you can use already existing caves systems with a few adaptations, much like a geyser but earthquake powered.

Single use should be possible with the technology though. Efficiency and uses aside, it is certainly possible.

Comment: the problem is finding a container the quake can't just destroy. it is the same problem with trying ot use a nuclear bomb for power, as long as all the energy is released all at once it will overwhelm any device

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the type of era you're suggesting. Harnessing that type of energy would already be really expensive currently in regards of money and physical resources.

Answer (score -1):

I would maybe use Piezoelectricity as explanation of generating power in this way. I don't know how sensible it would be but it sounds really interesting.

http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2012/ph240/garland1/ is a link to the use of this technology in roads with all the scientific data. With micro earthquakes that are near constant I would imagine similar to a road material simply burying the same type of material in layers seems like it would work. This was first discovered in the 1880's.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).